# Bootstrap Popover doesn't fall over the parent div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a SharePoint site. I created some page with a datatable. In each row there is a hyperlink. This hyperlink shows a bootstrap popover. The popover doesn't fall over the end of the parent div. I give the parent div a red border. I try something like giving the popover a high z-index but it didn't help.

[image]

I don't see all the content of the popover. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try using `overflow: visible`?